# What is the appropriate breakpoints for portfolio sorting (using CRSP stocks) based on size?

Tags: portfolio

I want to sort stocks based on size. I use CRSP database from 1962 to 2018. My question is that in order to create quintiles, ***what is the appropriate breakpoints? and how can I calculate them?***

I saw that Fama French calculated breakpoints based on NYSE. But I want to use CRSP database which consists of all the stocks listed on NYSE Amex and Nssdaq.

Thank you very very much

Comment: Fama and French also include NYSE+Amex+Nasdaq stocks, but they use only NYSE to determine the breakpoints for a reason: the number of small Nasdaq stocks included in CRSP varies over time and this would create serious inconsistencies in determining what is a 'small' stock. *I recommend using the same procedure as Fama French* ,i.e. quintiles of NYSE.

Comment: Thank you very much, just one more question. I used the Fama and French breakpoints table for size. is it OK to use that table?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to check their calculation (unless you want to).

Comment: Thank you a lot